Find Top 3 Students by Marks obtained in each subject using Stream API
We have Student class having properties studentId,name and List of Subject.With Subject class having properties studentId,subjectName and marks.We have list of students ,based on marks on each subjects find out top3 students using Stream API
package Streams;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class IdentifyAndPrintTop3StdsByMarksInEachSubj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student std1 = new Student(1001, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1001, "Maths", 87.0)
                ,new Subject(1001, "English", 72.0)));
        Student std2 = new Student(1002, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1002, "Maths", 77.0)
                ,new Subject(1002, "English", 83.0)));
        Student std3 = new Student(1003, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1003, "Maths", 91.0)
                ,new Subject(1003, "English", 68.0)));
        Student std4 = new Student(1004, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1004, "Maths", 76.0)
                ,new Subject(1004, "English", 51.0)));
        Student std5 = new Student(1005, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1005, "Maths", 51.0)
                ,new Subject(1005, "English", 65.0)));
        Student std6 = new Student(1006, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1006, "Maths", 57.0)
                ,new Subject(1006, "English", 55.0)));
        Student std7 = new Student(1007, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1007, "Maths", 98.0)
                ,new Subject(1007, "English", 92.0)));
        Student std8 = new Student(1008, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1008, "Maths", 45.0)
                ,new Subject(1008, "English", 48.0)));
        
        List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(std1,std2,std3,std4,std5,std6,std7,std8);
        

    }

}
class Student{
    private Integer studentId;
    private String name;
    private List<Subject> subjectList;
    
    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }
    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
    
    public Student(Integer studentId, String name, List<Subject> subjectList) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [studentId=" + studentId + ", name=" + name + ", subjectList=" + subjectList + "]";
    }
    
}
class Subject{
    private Integer studentId;
    
    private String subjectName;
    
    private Double marks;

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public Double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(Double marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Subject(Integer studentId, String subjectName, Double marks) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Subject [studentId=" + studentId + ", subjectName=" + subjectName + ", marks=" + marks + "]";
    }
    
    
}

I grouped it into subjectwise but dont know how to sort them by marks

Map<Object, List<Subject>> studentMap = studentList
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(t -> t.getSubjectList().stream())
                            .toList()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getSubjectName()))
                            ;

I want to find out top3 students based on their marks - subjectWise using Stream API. The top 3 students of each subject.

I think you need first to group students by Subject, then sort students by marks and take top 3.

why grouping by studentId? Can there be any ID with more than one entry?

@Dmitry543 agree with you.I gruped it by subject name but unable to sort it by marks

Please clarify: Do you want the top three students for each subject? Or the top 3 students overall? Or the 1 top student in each of 3 subjects? Or something else? Probably best if you specify exact expected result from your example.

@Anonymous i want top3 students of each subject

Thanks. Is that the student ID repeated in the Subject (1001 etc.)? Will that ID suffice in the result, or do you need the names or the full Student objects?

Bite the task into pieces.
First group the Subject objects into groups per subject (Maths in one group, English in another):
    // Find all Subject objects per subject name
    Map<String, List<Subject>> subjectsPerSubjectName = studentList.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.subjectList().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::subjectName));

This gives us all Subject objects, but we only want the top 3 for each subject. So sort and and take only the top 3 from each of the groups from before:
    // Take only top 3 scores per subject
    Map<String, List<Subject>> top3PerSubjectName = subjectsPerSubjectName.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Subject::score).reversed())
                            .limit(3)
                            .toList()));

If needed, find the Student objects for each Subject object again. Base on ID:
    // Find Students
    Map<String, List<Student>> top3StudentsPerSubject = top3PerSubjectName.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .map(sbj -> studentList.stream()
                                    .filter(st -> st.id() == sbj.id())
                                    .findAny()
                                    .orElseThrow())
                            .toList()));

By now we have discarded the connection between Student and Subject objects and re-established it using linear search over all students. I hope it’s clear that this is not the most efficient way. Please decide for yourself whether it’s appropriate for your amount of data and your purpose.
Print results:
    // Print
    top3StudentsPerSubject.forEach((k, v)
            -> System.out.println(k + ": "
                    + v.stream()
                            .map(st -> "" + st.id() + ' ' + st.name())
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));

Output is:
English: 1007 SanjayNaik, 1002 SanjayNaik, 1001 SanjayNaik
Maths: 1007 SanjayNaik, 1003 SanjayNaik, 1001 SanjayNaik

Depending on needs you can print other information.
For my code I have used the following record types:
record Student(int id, String name, List<Subject> subjectList) { }

record Subject(int id, String subjectName, double score) { }

Using records is the reason why I haven’t got get in my getter names. Please substitute your method names.
Keeping Student and Subject together
If we are required to keep the relationship between Student and Subject objects intact, create a record type to hold both. Then the basic idea is the same as before.
    record StudentAndSubject(Student student, Subject rankedSubject) { }

    // Create StudentAndSubject objects for each Subject and group into subject names
    Map<String, List<StudentAndSubject>> sasBySubjectName = studentList.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.subjectList().stream()
                    .map(subject -> new StudentAndSubject(student, subject)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sas -> sas.rankedSubject.subjectName()));

    // Take top 3 for each subject
    Map<String, List<StudentAndSubject>> top3BySubjectName = sasBySubjectName.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue()
                            .stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((StudentAndSubject sas)
                                    -> sas.rankedSubject().score()).reversed())
                            .limit(3)
                            .toList()));

This allows us to print both name and score of each student:
    // Print
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<StudentAndSubject>> sasEntry : top3BySubjectName.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(sasEntry.getKey());
        for (StudentAndSubject sas : sasEntry.getValue()) {
            System.out.format(Locale.ROOT, "    %4d %-14s %4.1f%n",
                    sas.student().id(), sas.student().name(), sas.rankedSubject().score());
        }
    }

Output:
English
    1007 SanjayNaik     92.0
    1002 SanjayNaik     83.0
    1001 SanjayNaik     72.0
Maths
    1007 SanjayNaik     98.0
    1003 SanjayNaik     91.0
    1001 SanjayNaik     87.0


I finally found out
Map<Object, Object> studentMap2 = studentList
                .stream()
                .flatMap(t -> t.getSubjectList().stream())
                .toList()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t ->t.getSubjectName()
                            ,Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                    Collectors.toList(),
                                        t -> t.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Subject::getMarks ).reversed())
                                        .limit(3)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                        )));
System.out.println(studentMap2);

Below is the result which i get
{English=[Subject [studentId=1007, subjectName=English, marks=92.0]
        , Subject [studentId=1002, subjectName=English, marks=83.0]
        , Subject [studentId=1001, subjectName=English, marks=72.0]], 
Maths=[Subject [studentId=1007, subjectName=Maths, marks=98.0],
       Subject [studentId=1003, subjectName=Maths, marks=91.0],
       Subject [studentId=1001, subjectName=Maths, marks=87.0]]}

Thanks @AliRaza Your answer helped.

@ArvindKumarAvinash, the code is different.


Group By subject not studentId as you want results for each subject
Once you group by subject, you must add some mechanism to limit the total result to your desired threshold.

Try this method:
public static Map<String, List<Students>> getTopStudentsBySubject(List<Student> students, int limit) {
    Map<String, List<Student>> topStudentsBySubject = students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Student::getSubject, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            list -> list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getMarks).reversed())
                .limit(limit)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    ));

    return topStudentsBySubject;

}

To use it:
public class IdentifyAndPrintTop3StdsByMarksInEachSubj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student std1 = new Student(1001, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1001, "Maths", 87.0)
                ,new Subject(1001, "English", 72.0)));
        Student std2 = new Student(1002, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1002, "Maths", 77.0)
                ,new Subject(1002, "English", 83.0)));
        Student std3 = new Student(1003, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1003, "Maths", 91.0)
                ,new Subject(1003, "English", 68.0)));
        Student std4 = new Student(1004, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1004, "Maths", 76.0)
                ,new Subject(1004, "English", 51.0)));
        Student std5 = new Student(1005, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1005, "Maths", 51.0)
                ,new Subject(1005, "English", 65.0)));
        Student std6 = new Student(1006, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1006, "Maths", 57.0)
                ,new Subject(1006, "English", 55.0)));
        Student std7 = new Student(1007, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1007, "Maths", 98.0)
                ,new Subject(1007, "English", 92.0)));
        Student std8 = new Student(1008, "SanjayNaik",Arrays.asList(new Subject(1008, "Maths", 45.0)
                ,new Subject(1008, "English", 48.0)));
        
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(std1,std2,std3,std4,std5,std6,std7,std8);

        Map<String, List<Student>> topStudentsBySubject = getTopStudentsBySubject(students, 3);

        topStudentsBySubject.forEach((subject, topStudents) -> {
            System.out.println(subject + ": " + topStudents);
        });
        
    }

    public static Map<String, List<Students>> getTopStudentsBySubject(List<Student> students, int limit) {
        Map<String, List<Student>> topStudentsBySubject = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Student::getSubject, 
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getMarks).reversed())
                    .limit(limit)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
        ));
    
        return topStudentsBySubject;
    
    }

}

